# How to omit the authentification dialog during URLRead?

Tags: front-end, web-access, dialog-window, automation

When I use `URLRead`

[image]

*Mathematica* will popup a window like:
[image]

Actually I have given the parameters `Password` and `Username` in `HTTPRequest`, but they seem invalid. Any programmatic method to fill this form so it won't popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### V11 update

For new functions it is enough to use documented `Interactive` option:

```
URLRead["https://httpbin.org/status/401", Interactive -> False]
```

Broken for `URLDownload` so here's a workaround:

[Authentication dialog for URLDownload / URLSave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143423/5478)

---

#### Pre V11 era, `URLFetch` and friends solutions

There is an undocumented option `DisplayProxyDialog` which prevents that:

```
URLFetch[
    "https://httpbin.org/status/401"
  , "StatusCode"
  , "DisplayProxyDialog" -> False
]
```

As OP noticed it works for `URLRead` even though it does not appear in `Options[URLRead]` in contrary to `Options[URLFetch]`.

When switched off you can handle 401 status code however you like, abort, prompt custom dialog etc.

---

I have not guessed it, WRI Support suggested it to my friend when he asked:

> [...] Just informed by our development group that there is such an option (all-be-it undocumented):
>
> "DisplayProxyDialog" -> False
>
> to omit the authentication dialog. [...]

So I suppose this makes it safe to use.

Comment: Would you mind tell me how did you find it?And actually I prefer to fill out this form than forbid its present.

Comment: @yode source added. you can create a loop to ask a user to feed credentials to your dialog and redo the call, or something like that.

Comment: This method solve the problem eventually.