# Authentication dialog for URLDownload / URLSave

Tags: bugs, front-end, web-access, dialog-window

**Bug introduced in 11.0 and persists through 11.3**

The original problem is was fixed in V11.2 but since then it returns `File[path/to/file/that/does/not/exits]` instead of `401` Failure/HTTPResponse like `URLRead` does.

> CASE:3877019 - confirmed

---

The second one prompts the dialog:

```
URLRead["https://httpbin.org/status/401", Interactive -> False]
```

```
URLDownload["https://httpbin.org/status/401", Interactive -> False]
```

but both should return 401 HTTPResponse since

> ref/URLDownload:
>
> `URLDownload` takes the options as `URLRead`.
>
> ref/URLRead
>
> `Interactive` - `True` - whether to allow interactive authentication dialogs

Have I missed something? Is there a workaround?

It probably can be narrowed to `URLSave` broken for `"DisplayProxyDialog" -> False`, but this is undocumented so I can't complain.

---

related:

[How to omit the authentification dialog during URLRead?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129051/how-to-input-the-popup-window-with-programally-method)

[Inconsistent Authorization Dialog (401) handling](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/139551/inconsistent-authorization-dialog-401-handling)

Comment: Interestingly enough, there is a symbol `URLUtilities\`PackageScope\`$options`, setting which with association `<|Interactive -> False|>` works for `URLRead` (you can call it without parameters now and it won't show a dialog), but it doesn't for `URLDownload`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before it is fixed one can use this quick workaround based on [How to get StatusCode without fetching Body/Content in the background](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/144038/5478):

```
DialoglessURLDownload =  URLFetch[
    #, "StatusCode", Method -> "HEAD", "DisplayProxyDialog" -> False
] /. (200 :> URLDownload[##]) &
```

I've decided I will return the status code for any case that isn't `200`, that is arguable but `URLDownload` itself gives non existing `File[...]` when it fails so I will not try to mimic wrong behavior. This at least gives you a possibility to react appropriately.

```
DialoglessURLDownload @ "https://httpbin.org/status/401"
```

> 401