# How to get StatusCode without fetching Body/Content in the background

Tags: functions, performance-tuning, import, web-access

I only need to know whether a specific call returns `200` but:

```
URLFetch[
    "http://exampledata.wolfram.com/10mb.dat"
  , "StatusCode"
] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {15.141, 200}
> ```

So it clearly downloads whole 10MB. Similar `curl` command returns almost instantaneously:

```
 curl -I http://exampledata.wolfram.com/10mb.dat
```

so it is clearly possible. How to do this so it will work on every V10+ installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
URLFetch["http://exampledata.wolfram.com/10mb.dat", "StatusCode", 
  Method -> "HEAD"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.383878, 200}

Comment: +1 for good dig.Though the color is red,it's seem [also serve](http://i.stack.imgur.com/afAiJ.png) for `URLRead`.And I'm in 11.1.