# What is the equivalent of curl?

Tags: web-access

The URL related functions have confused me yet again (I have v11.1)!

**What is the Mathematica equivalent for the following generic curl command?**

```
curl -u user:pass http://someurl.file --output filename
```

I tried what @Kuba suggested, but its options are colored like errors and it didn't work:

[image]

**Separate Issues:**

- `URLDownload` doesn't respect the `Interactive` option either:

[image]

**Follow-ups:**

- How can I do this for a long list of large images? e.g. is URLDownload multithreaded?
- How can I do these url downloads in a pauseable or resumable fashion?

Comment: What is your Mathematica version?

Comment: Take a look at documentation of `URLSave` or `URLDownload` for newer versions.

Comment: I have V11.1 @Szabolcs, I didn't see any mention about user/passwords in those docs

Comment: @user5601 it says URLDownload takes same options as URLRead so I guess `URLDownload["http://someurl.file", "filename", "Username" -> "user", 
 "Password" -> "pass"]`, does it work for you?

Comment: About Interactive issue: [143423](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143423/5478). p.s. have you tried with `URLSave`? The first message doesn't seem to be related to those options btw.

Comment: @user5601 you can also format a `HTTPRequest` and work with that. It shouldn't be any different than the raw `URLDownload`, but it's, perhaps, a bit cleaner and it's more OOP.

Comment: I don't understand, how did you get Authentication dialog if you claim you can't make it work?

Comment: @Kuba The dialog popping up means that the Interactive->False option wasn't working

Answer (score 11):

Assuming you're using Basic Authentication (vs. say, NTML Auth), the following code should work:

```
basicAuth[u_, p_] := "Basic " <> ExportString[u <> ":" <> p, "Base64"]
Import@URLRead@
  HTTPRequest[<|"Method" -> "GET", "Scheme" -> "https", 
    "Domain" -> "server.foo.com", "Port" -> 443,
    "Path" -> "/path/to.jpg",
    "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> basicAuth[username, password]}|>]
```

You'll want to change "Scheme" and "Port" for the HTTP instead of HTTPS.

Once you confirm that works, then you can switch to URLDownload:

```
URLDownload@
      HTTPRequest[<|"Method" -> "GET", "Scheme" -> "https", 
        "Domain" -> "server.foo.com", "Port" -> 443,
        "Path" -> "/path/to.jpg",
        "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> basicAuth[username, password]}|>]
```

I haven't tried it, but you should be able to create a bunch of `HTTPRequest[]` objects and pass them to `URLDownload[{req1,req2,...}]`.

Finally, I was surprised to find that `ExportString["...","Base64"]` adds a "\n" at the end of the resulting string. I thought I'd need to strip it out but I haven't seen it make a difference. YMMV.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you update this for v12.3?

Comment: @user5601 Just tried it in 12.3.1 and it worked fine. Was able to pull down the html from a server with basic auth enabled.