# Disable Authentication Popup

Tags: warning-messages, usage-messages

I'm doing my own server authentication that sends the authentication as a header. If the authentication is wrong, I want to print an error message, but instead Mathematica creates that authentication popup. I want to remove the popup and have the output from the wrong authentication generate an error message.

Comment: Try `Interactive->False` in your `URLRead`

Comment: I think those are duplicates but let me know if you disagree. Also, keep in mind this bug: [Authentication dialog for URLDownload / URLSave](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/143423/5478)

Comment: I'm using URLExecute which takes the same options as URLRead, but I am also making POST and DELETE requests. For these can I do: URLExecute[HTTPRequest[url,<|"Method"->"POST"|>, Interactive->False]]? Also, is there a reason to use URLRead over URLExecute?

Comment: @JoeBlow should work, doesn't it? The difference is that URLRead gives you more control and Execute shorter syntax, depends what fits your needs.